# How to make apply function like tailwind with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

if I have code like this

```
const AlignContent = {
    'content-start': {alignContent: 'flex-start'},
    'content-center': {alignContent: 'center'},
    'content-end': {alignContent: 'flex-end'},
    'content-stretch': {alignContent: 'stretch'},
    'content-between': {alignContent: 'space-between'},
    'content-around': {alignContent: 'space-around'},
}

const AlignItems = {
        'items-stretch': {alignItems: 'stretch'},
    'items-start': {alignItems: 'flex-start'},
    'items-center': {alignItems: 'center'},
    'items-end': {alignItems: 'flex-end'},
    'items-baseline': {alignItems: 'baseline'},
}


const styles = {
    ...AlignContent,
    ...AlignItems
}


function apply(styles: ??? ) {
  //apply code here
}
```

how to create interface ??? to be refer `keyof typeof styles`, so i want to called apply like this:

```
apply('items-stretch content-around')
```

**note**: ??? is not type `string` only, but i want to be suggested each from `keyof typeof styles`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) for that purpose.

In your case you can write something like:

```js
const AlignContent = {
    'content-start': {alignContent: 'flex-start'},
    'content-center': {alignContent: 'center'},
    'content-end': {alignContent: 'flex-end'},
    'content-stretch': {alignContent: 'stretch'},
    'content-between': {alignContent: 'space-between'},
    'content-around': {alignContent: 'space-around'},
}

type AlignContentKeys = keyof typeof AlignContent

const AlignItems = {
    'items-stretch': {alignItems: 'stretch'},
    'items-start': {alignItems: 'flex-start'},
    'items-center': {alignItems: 'center'},
    'items-end': {alignItems: 'flex-end'},
    'items-baseline': {alignItems: 'baseline'},
}

type AlignItemsKeys = keyof typeof AlignItems


const styles = {
    ...AlignContent,
    ...AlignItems
}

type Style = AlignContentKeys | AlignItemsKeys | `${AlignContentKeys} ${AlignItemsKeys}` | `${AlignItemsKeys} ${AlignContentKeys}`

function apply(styles: Style ) {
  //apply code here
}
```

You can check it out in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggGwJYHMwGFxQKZlgXhgG8AoGcmAclD1ygFpoBDAJykoC5ink1Na8XSgDME2AB6MordgF8ANGQrUsdesDrYWnbrwyrBVDbW0Kl5FQIa4AJjqI9U%20q0NET6tymYpGDDaCzYUMAAFvaOfH5CAUGhXoo%20ljh49ABGQQDu2LjhevzJUNEADkwaaZnZYPHmvlb0rCAArmB2XA55UVQQJWUNzXZmsiQkUACeRdjwHVYA0tijEDCEANbzIMIwYxPrU075dMM00LtoAJI4ALaLhKSJSJcQUoHBYW0RYOfYV9FQz3HeynuX0ezDYuScn2%20VDcklBcgSgIe6k02jeekhECExhwpgRFiBVw8LXBZwerjEkk8APxSNSTAg2GQYGwJI%20ZKodIZTJZg2GW0miAhDzmCyWMFWox2-J2gtJwOGJCOsGgozE12INQAdNrZc4CniYNrNbqMSQhiNxpMAMpjMRi3X7PAixYAHxObOBzpgboABgASIgOvzO2QwAMm4XzCCyH3emD%20wPoyMLUPh6YFEM%204bCZrAKBIcAwJhFIoIUYAChVaq4NtVkwAlBryAB6ZvF0ujGCgGyTEJabBmoA) I made.